# What kind of math do I study to learn about vectors?

Tags: vectors

I've taken up to Calculus II, and I don't remember anything about vectors.  What kind of math is the beginning point for learning them?  Linear algebra?

Edit:. If it is Linear Algebra, do I pick the version that uses matrices?

Comment: Linear algebra. Duh.

Comment: Is la the beginning of it?

Comment: Basic knowledge of linear algebra is enough, I feel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll generally see a bit of vectors first in one of these courses:

- Intro physics (Mechanics or E&M)
- Vector Calculus / Multivariable Calculus
- Differential Equations (often the course is coupled with a bit of linear algebra)
- Linear Algebra

If you want to learn about vectors, a linear algebra book (e.g. Strang's Linear Algebra and Its Applications) is a good place to start.

Comment: Does it help to take Linear Algebra before Physics?

Comment: Thats a question for your advisor and what kind of linear algebra course you would take. Most people (at least in the US) will take physics before linear algebra, though.

Answer (score 1):

From wiki: "Linear algebra is the branch of mathematics concerning vector spaces and linear mappings between such spaces."

Hence, if you want to study vectors, you are essentially doing linear algebra, whether on the course of the same name, or somewhere else. In my opinion, it is better to take linear algebra course sooner than later, since you will encounter it in most of other fields of mathematics. I'm not sure what you mean by "version that uses matrices" since all "versions" use matrices. It just depends on order that material is presented if you will learn lots about matrices, then use that knowledge for other stuff, or the other way around.